# What is the origin of (buying produce) "by the each"?

Tags: terminology, phrase-origin

At the grocery store, I find produce sold by the pound, by the bag, and "by the each".  I would never say produce was priced by the piece or by the item.

Where does this come from?  Each is not a noun, which deserves an article.

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/453265/picked-as-an-each-sold-as-an-each-grammatically-correct) asks if it is grammatical.  To me, the usage is common, and I accept it. I am asking where it comes from.

Comment: Where do they sell things “by the each”?? I’ve never heard that.  I’ve seen prices marked 30 cents each. And $2.00 a pound  but I’ve never seen “by the” used with each.

Comment: @Jim - https://www.google.com/search?q=by+the+each&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it&prmd=isvn&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjkgfLEkcPuAhWLQEEAHVzNA0oQ_AUoAXoECA4QAQ&biw=768&bih=909

Comment: @user66974 -  Well regardless, I think it weird and and I’m sorry to learn it’s a thing.

Comment: @Jim - it is just wholesale industry jargon, no need to worry much.

Answer (score 2):

The same issue appears on a [Language Log](https://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=18186) post where they suggest it is an intra-industry jargon probably  derived from similar common expressions  such as “by the piece”:

> A reddit thread suggests it arose out of intra-industry jargon to distinguish items priced e.g. “$2.99 each” from items priced by the pound or by the quart or what have you,* with additional commenters saying there’s a usage among  people who work in warehouses and similar environments  who use nominalized “each” contrastively with “case”  (so if you need a co-worker to get you a quantity that’s more than 12 cases but less than 13 cases “you might say ‘hey mike, 12 cases 3 eaches.’”

[image] From (riverfronttimes.com/newsblog)

See other usage examples of “prices by the each” [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%20by%20the%20each&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwio0-2PksPuAhVPuKQKHbG5DPIQ2-cCegQIABAC&oq=%20by%20the%20each&gs_lcp=ChJtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1pbWcQAzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzIECAAQEzoICAAQCBAHEB5Q0x5YvSJgySdoAHAAeACAAW-IAasEkgEDNS4xmAEAoAEBwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-img&ei=tgsVYKigJs_wkgWx87KQDw&bih=909&biw=768&prmd=isvn&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIT753IT753&hl=it).